# FirebaseAuth.getInstance returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have just started using Firebase Authentication, I followed few tutorials including Firebase's docs, but no matter what I do, FirebaseAuth.getInstance() always returns null.
After trying for a long time, I decided to delete everything I've done related to the Authentication, and start it over, so that I only use the declaration of  the FirebaseAuth variable and its initialization, as in the following:
In the class variables initialization:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

And then in the onCreate() method I called a method which initializes firebase's variables and references, so I call the following method:

```
private void initFirebase()     //initialize firebase
    {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");
        mEventsReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("events");
        mStorageRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        defaultRef = mStorageRef.child("usersProfilePic/");             //Assigning default reference for storage
    }
```

My dependencies in the build.gradle are:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    /*dataBinding {
        enabled = true;
    }*/
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.aln4"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //google maps api
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    //Calendar
    implementation 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'
    implementation 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.khacpv:Calendar-Day-View:1.0.5'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //Image tools
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    //Validation
    implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:2.0'
    //Notification badge
    implementation 'com.nex3z:notification-badge:0.1.0'
    //Others
    implementation 'com.kevin:loopview:1.4.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

In the Firebase authentication website itself, I've already enabled the Authentication service in the sign-in method.

So, if anyone can tell me what is wrong here, I'd love that since I've spent the last 6 hours trying to figure it out...

Comment: Are you trying to get the current logged in user?

Comment: most likely the `google-service.json` is missing or the Google Play services plugin had not been applied... it would require both `build.gradle` to answer this reliable.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi I'm just trying to get something inside the mAuth variable to use it afterwards... Doesn't really matter what...

Comment: @MartinZeitler I've already regenerated the google-service.json file and replaced with the previous one, and I applied the google services plugin

Comment: @AdiHarel `this` might not be `instanceof Context`, on the previous call to `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)`. are you calling it within the scope of an `Activity`? because when it fails, the following call most likely will fail, too.

Comment: If you are logged in then it will return something otherwise return null.

Comment: @MartinZeitlerMar this is in an activity.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi It doesn't make any sense... FirebaseAuth.getInstance won't get called if I'm not logged in...? So how do I login in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#initializeApp(android.content.Context)) at least tells, what `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` returns:

> the default `FirebaseApp`, if either it has been initialized previously, **or Firebase API keys are present in string resources**. Returns `null` otherwise.

make sure to apply the Google Services plugin at the bottom of the `build.gradle`, after the `android` block... because this is where those `API keys in string resources` originate from.

which is the only logical explanation for `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` returning `null`.

---

this one is added twice: `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2`.

the version mismatch can be solved by exclusion:

```
implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "recyclerview-v7"
}
```

so that it will use `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0` instead.

Comment: I just added my whole build.gradle file into the original post, see the edit

Comment: @AdiHarel the problem is `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true` ...these version conflicts need to be fixed first - because hiding the problem won't fix the problem.

Comment: How do i do it? just delete this part?

Comment: @AdiHarel bediuk. then it should complain about version mismatches.

Comment: I deleted it, still returns null

Comment: Yeah I saw it, deleted the implemetation and pasted the one you told me to paste, and still null

Comment: @AdiHarel try to clean/make the project once. the build log needs to have this one line: `Parsing json file: .../src/debug/google-services.json`, then the credentials should have been applied to the string resources - and `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` should work, which is the precondition for `FirebaseAuth` to work.

Comment: That edit you just wrote is not correct, I changed the places implemetation to what you just said and it just gave me a lot of errors in my code...

Comment: about the cleaning and building, where is that "build log" and how do I search it and when exactly?

Comment: @AdiHarel you can keep on with the deprecated version, but it will stop working on July 29, 2019 ...in terms of simply being switched off. you may keep it as a comment for now, but still this should be something to consider. see https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: alright, thanks, I'll keep that in mind, and will switch to the new one later

Comment: Do you have a solution for my problem maybe?

Comment: @AdiHarel the answer already solves the version mismatch - and I've thoroughly explained why it happens - and how to fix it. that the`google-services.json` is in the wrong place could also be an issue, there are alike 3 locations where they are being picked up. while `FirebaseApp` won't work, `FirebaseAuth` won't neither, because it depends on it. also double check the added key fingerprints.

Comment: I've already deleted the version mismatch line in the build.gradle file, regenerated the google-service.json file and made sure it's in the right place. The FirebaseApp does work, I ran the debugger and made sure it has some value in it and it does. By the way., the FirebaseDatabase has some value in it as well. I really don't know what the problem is

Comment: hey, sorry to bring this back up. It's not related to the question but couldnt find a way to contact you other than here.. I remember you told me that there's a way for me to send push notifications to specific users with firebase but through the code and not manually with fcm... I've been looking for it in a minute but couldnt find it...

Answer (score -1):

getInstance() is for checking if user is logged in or not. null means you are not logged in.

Comment: this is incorrect. just see https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getInstance()

Comment: I wrote you in the comments of the post. It doesn't make sense cause it means I cant log in in the first place, cause the default state is that I'm logged out

Answer (score -1):

Add this to you manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
```

If same service exists, add simpy meta-data tag.